# Why mongodb is so slow in authenticate?

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I use mongodb 1.6.5  master/slave
The performance of mongodb is not as I excepted, and I found many slow logs about auth.

here it is:
Mon Dec  5 18:46:31 [conn45072] query XXX.$cmd ntoreturn:1 command: { authenticate: 1, user: "ixxx", nonce: "2c9f7cxxxx1608ff", key: "3dd3b3xxxxd2ba66f4754a429d125095" } reslen:53 8165ms

when upgrad 1.6.5 to 1.8.4, the problem still existed.

when I restart my mongodb, the process of auth seems become much more faster, but still very slow, it costs almost 2000ms to auth.

Comment: Any updates on this one? Would be great to hear if upgrading helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest upgrading to the latest release? (2.0.1 as of this writing)

It should be relatively fast. How are you authenticating, via a driver or directly via the mongo client?

Comment: I used C# drive . I will try other language driver, if the problem still existed, I will upgrade to 2.0.1

Comment: Did upgrading the driver actually help? If so, by how much? We're using dotCloud and can't upgrade our driver because we're using mongoid and it requires mongodb 2.x to upgrade, but dotCloud only provides 1.8.x. If this actually fixes the issue, we would consider pushing for faster adoption of 2.x, but if this is just a Hail Mary then I don't want to make too much trouble for them (they value stability over having the newest shiny).